# Create CSE Array Formula in Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

i have very recently started to learn to create VBA macros in Excel, however, I am completely stumped as to how to create a CSE array formula within my macro

I would like to define a variable as the row in which the value in column A in a sheet = value 1 and column B = value 2

within excel itself, the formula below works perfectly:
`{=Match(1,(A:A=1)*(B:B=2),0)}`

However, I would now like to use it within my macro along the lines of:
`variable = {=Match(1,(Sheets("Right Sheet").range("A:A")=value1)*(Sheets("Right Sheet").range("B:B")=value2),0)}`

Anyone able to provide any light on this?
I have played with all sorts of variants of `ArrayFormula` and had no success at all!
Ideally I would like my `value1` and `value2` numbers to be equal to variables (1 and 2) defined previously in my macro

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (eg) worked for me:

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("SUM(A1:A5*B1:B5)")
```

you need to build up the formula into a string, and leave off the "=" and "{}".

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("Match(1,(Sheet1!A:A=" & val1 & _
                                  ")*(Sheet1!B:B=" & val2 & "),0)")
```